# Fixed Bottom Aligned Div

Tags: css

I need a footer in the bottom of a page, which is overlaps any content that will make the page scroll. Also, when scrolling down, it the footer still need to stay there.

Is this possible with css only working for IE6+ ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSS only technique for a fixed bottom footer with variable height, no tables, no overlap](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29835813/css-only-technique-for-a-fixed-bottom-footer-with-variable-height-no-tables-no)

Answer (score 6):

Recently I used the following style:

```
div.BottomDisclaimer
{
  z-index:100;
  position:fixed;
  bottom:0px;
  border-top-style: solid;
  border-top-width: 1pt;
  padding-top: 4px;
}
```

Comment: You can fold the border-top-* declarations into "border-top: 1pt solid". (Also, might you be better off using pixels?)

Comment: same goes here as for Moayad's sollution, IE6 doesn't support "position:fixed", so this will only work on IE7+

Answer (score 1):

Do a quick google search for CSS footer, and you'll find plenty solutions. But most solutions seem to work like this:

```
<body>
  <div id="wrapper">
     Main content
  </div>
  <div id="footer">
     Footer content
  </div>
</body>
```

and then applying css:

```
body, html { height: 100% }
#wrapper { height: 100% }
#footer {
  height: 150px;
  margin-top: -150px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

EDIT : because IE6 doesn't support position:fixed;, here's [a good workaround](http://www.cssplay.co.uk/layouts/fixed.html).

Comment: position: fixed is not supported by IE6, so this doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

For IE6, it's not possible to use `position:fixed`. You can use Dean Edwards' [IE7 library](http://dean.edwards.name/ie7/) to get that behavior if you want.