# CSS only technique for a fixed bottom footer with variable height, no tables, no overlap

Tags: html, css

As mentioned in the title, here are the requirements:

- a footer that must always be at the bottom of the viewport (no pushdown)
- css only
- height based on the content of the footer (variable)
- somehow prevent overlap of the main content element - when scrolled down
- no tables

---

header

---

content

---

footer

---

if you remove any of the requirements, I know how to do it, but not with all requirement intact.
does anyone know a solution?

Comment: the codez is what I am looking for XD

Comment: What about using any CSS framework?

Comment: something like SASS or LESS? that would be an option.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Keep footer with variable height on bottom](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9126777/keep-footer-with-variable-height-on-bottom)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To put the footer on the bottom you can use a variation of the following:

```
.some-footer {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%
}
```

The problem with this is that the main content will be behind the footer and you won't be able to scroll it up. And you can't just put a `padding-bottom` on the content because you don't know the footer's height.

I would recommend putting a duplicate of the footer after the content, but this one with `position: relative`, and with `opacity: 0`. This way you can always scroll until all the content is visible, independently of the footer's height.

Comment: that actually works the way I want it to. I don't like it because it is a hack, but the invisible footer really does it's job. I will wait a bit and see if somebody knows a clean solution, before I accept your answer :) thank you very much.

Answer (score -1):

This should work as you want! :) It will always be at the bottom of the page.
This will always be at the bottom of the viewport, NO MATTER WHAT! :D

```css
#footer{
  height: auto;
  min-height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: blue;
  bottom: 0px;
  position: fixed;
  display: block;
  z-index: 100000;
}
```

```html
<div id="footer">
</div>
```

Comment: his problem is not that he doesn't know how to set position fixed. it's that he doesnt know how to prevent the content from flowing beneath the footer, which could be a variable height. I dont think it is possible with just css

Comment: Position fixed will allow it to stick to the bottom of the page. The above code works perfectly.

Comment: Once again, he knows that. he wants it to "somehow prevent overlap of the main content element" so if the viewport is 600px tall, and the footer is 200px, and the content is 800px, he wants the content to be 400px and overflow scroll before it goes beneath the footer. Footer is variable height, so he doesnt know it will always be a set number, which means he wants calculated heights where elements use other elements to determine size.

Comment: as kai qing already told, your solution ignores the 4th requirement. or can you tell me how to set a "body" div in a way, that once you have completely scrolled down in the page, no overlapping occures?